# Fat arrow delegation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am converting some code to ES6, and in one part I am trying to understand fat arrow binding. I had code like this:

```
function callApi(api, payload, header) {
    $http.post(api, payload, header)
    .success(function(data) {...})
    .error(function (data, status) { handleError(data, status) })
}

function handleError(data, status) {...}
```

I have changed that to this, which works:

```
callApi(api, payload, header) {
    this.$http.post(api, payload, header)
    .success((data) => {...})
    .error((data, status) => this.handleError(data, status))
}

handleError(data, status) {...}
```

What doesn't work is when I tried to call handleError like this:

```
.error((data, status) => this.handleError)
```

I thought that might be delegating the error handling to the handleError function, but it doesn't.  Can someone help me understand what I'm misunderstanding about arrow binding that it can't be used like ()=>myFunction, and is there a way to do delegation like this that incorporates binding `this`?

Comment: `(a, b) => c` is the same as `function(a, b){return c}.bind(this)`

Comment: it should just be `.error(handleError)` no need for ES6 for that to work correctly.

Comment: `.error(handleError) ` results in "handleError not defined".
`.error(this.handleError)` rsesults in an error inside handleError when I try to use `this` that `this` is undefined.

Comment: `.error(this.handleError.bind(this))`

Comment: Thanks, this worked: `error(this.handleError.bind(this))`

Can I mark a comment as the accepted answer?

Comment: How about these answers? They go in more detail on the usage of `bind`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287925/mastering-javascript-function-bind

Comment: @Kip: Can you show us the implementation of `handleError` please, especially how it uses `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have changed that to `(data, status) => this.handleError(…)` which works

I'm worried if both `handleError` and `this.handleError` work. This could suggest that you have placed them in the global scope and are calling your functions without a receiver. I'd suggest to call the direct reference (only `handleError(…)`) and use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (which becomes default with ES6 anyway).

> What doesn't work is when I tried to call handleError like this: `(data, status) => this.handleError`

Well, simple: you're not *calling* it here, you've written an arrow function that returns the `handleError` function.

You should be able to simplify your code though by not using an arrow function at all:

```
callApi(api, payload, header) {
    this.$http.post(api, payload, header)
    .success((data) => {...})
    .error(handleError)
}
```

Or if `handleError` is a method of `this` though and relies on being called on the instance, you'd use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
….error(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

In that case, your original ES5 should not have worked however?!

Comment: Thanks.  @elclanrs said something similar above.  This worked for me: `.error(this.handleError.bind(this))`

Answer (score 0):

The `this` value for an arrow function is the `this` of the containing function. It doesn't create it's own `this`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this